# Building up a mountain, directional derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

A mountain has the shape of an elliptic paraboloid $$z=c−ax^2−by^2$$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive constants, $x$ and $y$ are the east-west and north-south map coordinates and $z$ is the altitude above sea level (measured in meters). An engineer wishes to build a railroad up the mountain. Straight up is much too steep. At the point $(1,1)$, in what directions may the track be laid so that it will be climbing with a $3%$ grade - that is, an angle whose tangent is $.03$.

**My attempt:** I rearranged it to be $$c = z+0.026x^2+0.015y^2$$ I found the gradient of this to be $(0.054x, 0.03y, 1)$. At $(1,1)$ it is simply $(0.054, 0.03, 1)$. Now I need to have some vector $\vec{u}$ so that $(0.054, 0.03, 1)$ dot product with $(u_1,u_2,u_3) = 0.03$.

I'm a little lost here, am I doing this correctly? Any push in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: Well I would drop 1 at the end of your gradient, since the gradient of a function of x,y which is what an eliptic paraboloid is , is just a vector $<f_x,f_y>$, so its just a vector $<u_1,u_2>$ for what you need. This is all true since these are level curves, not level surfaces

Comment: Okay yeah I was considering doing that. Once I do that though, u_1, u_2, won't be easy to solve for. Actually, impossible. Do you think I should just express them in terms of eachother?

Comment: I think this might help. The level curve that covers the most area is $c=ax^2by^2$ so the terminal of your vector you need should be bound such that $c>=a (x_1)^2+b (y_1)^2$ where x_1,y_1 is the terminal of the vector in the direction of the unit vector you need although there are infinite solutions for the terminal. But if you don't know c I don't think this does much. I'll have to think about this more.

Comment: Nah, we don't know c. With expressing the gradient in terms of solely x and y I can get that it goes in the direction of the vector u=(u_1, 1-1.8u_1)

Comment: Even there are infinite there is only 1 on the level curve z=c. So you would have two equation $c=ax^2+by^2$ and .054x+.03y=.03. But this is only if u have c.

Comment: Actually I believe ur way works. You should be able to pick any u_1

Comment: Actually you then do $(u_1)^2+(1-1.8u_1)^2=1$ Since it's a unit vector